# cannot install wordpress, appache2 shows me errors

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, apache, opensuse

I'm using OpenSuse as OS and I want to setup wordpress, 
When i go to the URL: localhost/wp-admin/install.php to install it, it shows me a blank web page.

a **tail -f /var/log/apache2/error_log** shows me the following:

```
[Thu Mar 09 09:42:19.791559 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 1453] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Thu Mar 09 09:42:19.905721 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1453] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Linux/SUSE) OpenSSL/1.0.1i-fips PHP/5.6.30 configured -- resuming normal operations 
[Thu Mar 09 09:42:19.905770 2017] [core:notice] [pid 1453] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd2-prefork -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -D SYSTEMD -D FOREGROUND' 
[Thu Mar 09 19:52:23.863004 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 1318] AH01882: Init: this version of mod_ssl was compiled against a newer library (OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015, version currently loaded is OpenSSL 1.0.1i-fips 6 Aug 2014) - may result in undefined or erroneous behavior AH00557: httpd2-prefork: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for linux-kny7 AH00558: httpd2-prefork: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message 
[Thu Mar 09 19:52:33.915213 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 1318] AH01882: Init: this version of mod_ssl was compiled against a newer library (OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015, version currently loaded is OpenSSL 1.0.1i-fips 6 Aug 2014) - may result in undefined or erroneous behavior
 [Thu Mar 09 19:52:33.915299 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 1318] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Thu Mar 09 19:52:35.175637 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1318] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Linux/SUSE) OpenSSL/1.0.1i-fips PHP/5.6.30 configured -- resuming normal operations [Thu Mar 09 19:52:35.175813 2017] [core:notice] [pid 1318] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd2-prefork -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -D
```

I need help please.

Comment: what's the output of the following command: `service apache2 status` ?

Comment: Loaded: loaded(/usr/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled)

Comment: Active: active(running)

Comment: Status: "total requests: 0; current requests/sec: 0; Current traffic: 0B/sec"